# Dealing with pdf files

Tags: flutter, pdf, django-rest-framework, stream, embed

I am implementing an application which its main idea is reading books using it.
the pdf files are on my server and I want the user to read the book without saving it on their device.

I thought about **streaming** the pdf file or **embedding** it. but it has some difficulties.

So, what is the best solution for this issue?

I am using **Django-Rest-framework** and **Flutter**

Comment: If you  are consuming the api, just display the file endpoint, however, if you are building the endpoint add a FileField(), configure django to receive file archives with Pillow and display the archives path/url into your endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use list of this packages for reading pdf files into flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer

Comment: are these packages don't require saving the pdf file in the user device?

Comment: yes bro just give your pdf links to it and enjoy it's fetures